# Calculating collisions in real time - dealing with a delay in time

Tags: math, real-time, physics

Suppose:

- you're coding a program in which 3 (or a lot more) circles (or other geometry) move around on the screen in real time, all with a different velocity, that can change at certain times due to physics-calculations.
- the calculations can only be calculated on every frame
- each frame, you have to make sure the circles who "collide"/"have collided during the time between this frame and the last" with each other will 'bounce off' by using physics-calculations
- Suppose that during the time between frame x and frame x+1, three circles will collide with each other. However, during frame x none of the circles touches the other. In frame x+1, the same thing applies (none collides)
  I will try to better illustrate this with an image:

[image]

**The question:**

What are good ways to keep track of collision like this, so that a collision wouldn't get skipped due to some (unexpected) large delay in time between two frames?

*This question has been spooking around in my head for way too long...*

### EDIT:

*To everyone thinking this post is OT: see [this](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/18515/calculating-collisions-in-realtime-dealing-with-a-delay-in-time) before you vote for closure.*

Comment: @xcrypt: Since your profile mentions game development, and I suspect this is part of a physics engine for some game, I suggest gamedev.stackexchange.com for future questions of this sort

Comment: @MikaelÖhman You have no idea what this post has been through :) It appears that this question belongs on SO. It is in fact for a physics engine, but I didn't restrict my question to that because *I don't want to restrict* it to that. Besides, most game developers *use* physics engines, only a few can be bothered to actually make one. - see http://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/18515/calculating-collisions-in-realtime-dealing-with-a-delay-in-time

Comment: See this series of blog posts: http://www.wildbunny.co.uk/blog/2011/03/25/speculative-contacts-an-continuous-collision-engine-approach-part-1/ http://www.wildbunny.co.uk/blog/2011/04/06/physics-engines-for-dummies/ http://www.wildbunny.co.uk/blog/2011/04/20/collision-detection-for-dummies/

Comment: @user57368 Incredibly helpful links

Answer (score 2):

To do this properly:

- calculate *exact* collision times for your circles instead of rounding to the next frame:

  - if your objects are moving in more than 1D, this requires root-finding.
- resolve collisions in order, as follows:

  - stop the simulation at the aforementioned exact collision time.
  - resolve the physics of the circles in this first collision.
  - recalculate to determine any collisions due to the new trajectories.
  - restart the simulation.
  - repeat until you reach end-of-frame without a collision.
- any other unscheduled change in physics will also require updating upcoming collisions.

You may notice that this has the potential for lots of computation.  It can be particularly nasty in cases where your balls lose kinetic energy and end up resting on each other -- if your physics makes this likely, you will need to add some sort of threshold for "resting contact" (which, unfortunately, can complicate your physics enormously).

---

Update, in response to comments:  I want to make clear that my answer ignores one of your assumptions -- you can't handle collisions accurately if you pretend that there isn't any time between frame boundaries.  The collisions don't happen at the frame boundaries; in general, the collisions will happen *between* the frame boundaries, so your computations need to reflect that.

If you assume that all motion between frames is linear (i.e., your simulation does all acceleration on the frame boundaries), then determining whether, where, and when there is a collision is actually pretty simple.  It reduces your interframe "simulation" to practically nothing -- you can solve your equations in closed form, even if your simulation is 2D or 3D:

```
posAB = posA - posB                [relative vector between circles A and B]
velAB = velA - velB                [relative velocity between circles A and B]
posAB(t) = posAB(0) + t * velAB    [relative vector as a function of time]
rAB = rA + rB                      [sum of radii of the two circles]
collision happens when distance(t) = abs(posAB(t)) == rAB
-> rAB^2 = | posAB(t) |^2 = | posAB(0) + t * velAB |^2
-> t^2 * |velAB|^2 + t * 2*posAB(0).velAB + |posAB(0)|^2 - rAB^2 == 0
solve quadratic equation for t:
   - if discriminant is negative, there is no collision.
   - if collision times are outside current timestep, there is no current collision.
   - otherwise, smallest t should be the correct collision time.
   - watch out for cases like 2 circles coming *out* of collision...
```

Finally, it sounds like you're trying to do premature optimization.  Better to make things work right, then make them fast;  you won't know your actual bottlenecks until you have running code.  I also think you are, in fact, underestimating the power of modern computers.  Of course, you can always add enough objects to bog down your computer, but I think you will be surprised how many it takes...

Comment: Sounds beautiful in theory, but the question is: When do you calculate the collision? in frameX, or in frameX+1? 

In the case of frameX, how would you know how far in time you have to calculate? You can estimate this by using the time of the last time_elapsed plus some offset, but there's no way you can know it for sure?

In the case of frameX+1, how would you know if you need to test for collision or not? the objects could have *passed* each other  entirely, so you wouldn't know to test or not. I suppose you could check on *everything*, but that sounds like a nearly impossible computation.

Comment: Especially when you have a lot of objects that need to be checked upon.

Either that or I am seriously underestimating the limits of a modern computer-system.

*(btw: with frameX I mean checks before the collision happen, and with frameX+1 I mean checks after the collision has happend [by using variables stored in previous frames])*

Comment: You can do conservative collision detection, by using a sphere or box that surrounds anywhere your object can travel within the current frame.  Then, using an acceleration structure, you can efficiently eliminate most possible collisions, and only need check for exact collisions where they are likely to actually happen.

Comment: But that seems impossible in theory. Since [1]there's no way you can know for certain how much time there is left until the next frame, and [2]in theory your object can travel anywhere, because it's current velocity can be changed by collisions that will apply forces, or external forces etc (all in one frame!)

Do you know any good sources of information about this?

Comment: I really appreciate that you try to explain it in your answer but I fear this topic is way to large to be completely covered here.

Comment: [1]: Maybe there's something in your setup I don't understand.  You know exactly how much time is left until the next frame -- you're the one who sets them up!  And if, for some reason, you feel your frame period is too long, you can always split it up however is convenient.

Comment: [2]: When an object suffers a collision, you should create a new bounding box for the remaining portion of the frame, and query your acceleration structure to see if there are any new potential collisions.  If you have acceleration within the frame (instead of only at the frame boundaries, as described in my update), you should be able to find an upper bound on that acceleration, and use that to determine your conservative bounding box.

Answer (score 1):

The idea of things only being evaluated in "frames" is probably not right.

One of the oldest OO patterns is "[Model-View-Controller](http://c2.com/cgi/wiki?ModelViewController)" - which encourages the *decoupling* of **what** is being viewed (the Model) with **how** it is viewed (the View).

A physics engine operates on model objects, and so would be tracking interactions between them **all the time** - so when the View comes along and asks for the position and direction of each circle in your "Frame x+1" scenario, it can easily answer, based on how much real time has passed since the last View request.

Answer (score 1):

I know your question states that the physics can only be evaluated at each frame, but I don't understand when this would be the case. It would be straightforward to incrementally update the physics in sufficiently small steps to avoid objects completely bypassing each other, once for each step.

However, sticking to an explicit update scheme (velocity times time step) only works for low velocities. As can be seen in many physics based games, upping the velocities can often lead to penetrating objects. 
Most simple physics engines opt to just allow for these bugs, because robust [collision detection](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Collision_detection) is notourisly difficult and costly.

If one limits the applicability to just circular shapes there are things that can be done. Writing the distance of the objects, as a function of time (over the time step)

```
x_a = x0_a + v_a*t
x_b = x0_b + v_b*t
d_ab = norm(x_a-x_b) = norm(x0_b-x0_a + (v_b-v_a)*t) = norm(dx + dv*t)
```

if the distance function `d_ab` equals the sum of the radii `r_a+r_b` for any `t` during the time step, then you have collision. So checking which objects collide (if any) first, then continuing from that point and redoing the analysis until the end of the time step has been reached. Quite complicated, and still only applies to circles/spheres.

Comment: I have thought about using similar methods, but that seems really costly. Also, there is no guarantee that this will always work due to the differences in 'lengths' of the velocities and the differences that can occur in time steps.

Comment: The second part of my answered gives some details on how you should go about to find the collision time **analytically**. You need to solve for `t`: `d_ab = r_a+r_b`. For anything more complicated than a few circles this becomes very tedious and extremely costly. I don't think any game engine does this, they either go for the non-robust explicit method, or fake it.

Answer (score 1):

The keywords of collision-detection here are "continuous" or "not continuous".

Just like some of the other answers write, most modern collision-libraries go with the non-continuous version because it is costly to analyze the exact collision-time for many collision-shapes. This means you let the objects interpenetrate, detect this, then adjust their velocities to counter the interpenetration. And just like has been noted, this allows fast-moving objects to pass each other. This is solved by increasing the frequency you run the physics, essentially you need to decouple it from the rendering (run it using a much faster timer). The actual way you solve for the resolution of the interpenetration etc. is in scope for a different question.

However, for circles, the fact that you can analytically solve for the exact collision-time for any pair of circles with constant (or accelerating) velocity gives you a possibility to do continuous collision-detection in this particular case. It would be a nice project, but I'm not sure if it is the right way since you might suddenly want to include other shapes and then you're stuck. The formulas you have to solve was already posted as an answer.

What I wanted to add here apart from summarizing the two methods, because you seem very concerned about the processing speed of a "modern computing system", is that computers now are blazingly fast doing any of these calculations even in the naive way of checking all pairs of circles, if you optimize the inner code somewhat. You probably have no problem at all upping the speed of the physics compared to the rendering also, for solving the non-continuous case of high velocities.

What a non-continuous engine adds to avoid pair-checking all objects is to use some kind of data structure to keep track of objects and their general position and occupancy in space to detect *potential* overlaps without having to check every object against every object. This is called a *broadphase* in shop-talk. You definitely need to implement something like this eventually if you start increasing the number of objects. You don't state what a "large" number of circles are or the CPU you are targeting, so hopefully you can skip this and do it the simple way as a start but it is difficult to say unless you post your use-case.

**Bottomline**: I would go for the tried and tested non-continuous engine type, at a sufficient physics frequency to avoid the high-velocity-skipping case, and don't worry about performance. If you are actually interested in coding this for a game, and don't want to take care of the details, you could simply use some of the existing 2D physics libraries like [Chipmunk](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chipmunk_physics_engine) or [Box2D](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Box2D). I'm not familiar with their implementations but I'm sure they are good ways to learn the subject too if you study the code.

Comment: we should expand the thought to complex 3D meshes: I gave the example of circles to keep things simple, but I really meant it as a general case. I want to make an engine so I can use it in games yes, but I am also interested in more scientific simulations, that's why I didn't restrict the question to games :)

You can indeed run the collision layer at a higher frequency than the graphics layer, I have done so in the past, but that doesn't guarantee anything, just helps. On top of that it seems rather expensive too.